# Get dynamically inserted element without using id

Tags: jquery

Dynamically, I create a new element with this method:

```
$("#elementA").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").after($(document.createElement("tr"));
});
```

I would want to get the new TR element to operate with it. But I don't want to give it an **id**. How can I get it?

**UPDATE:**

I would want to do something like this with the new element:

```
$new_tr_element.attr("data-url", "some.php");
```

Comment: You may use class then

Comment: Have you considered storing the element into a variable?

Comment: I don't want to use class or any other attribute either. Is it possible?

Comment: How do I store it in a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

store it in a variable

```
$("#elementA").on("click", function() {
    var obj = $(document.createElement("tr"));
    $(this).closest("tr").after(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

one way to  get this, is to  get the last `<tr>`.. using `last()`;

```
 $('#tableID tr:last');
```

try this

```
$("#elementA").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").after($(document.createElement("tr"));
  $('#tableID tr:last');  //this will give you the last `<tr>` in the table which will be the ``<tr>` u just appended
});
```

and other is , storing it in a variable so that you can use it later..

```
  $("#elementA").on("click", function() {
     var newTR= $(document.createElement("tr"));
      $(this).closest("tr").after(newTR);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$("#elementA").on("click", function() {
  var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
  $(this).closest("tr").after(tr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After returns a jQuery object. How about just grabbing the return value in a variable like so:

```
tr = $(this).closest("tr").after($(document.createElement("tr"));
```